# how to count and order word present in column in mysql table

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by, aggregate-functions

I have table with words column as below

```
stt_id | stt_hashtag           |stt_country |stt_time|
1      |ClimateAction CleanSeas|in          |1582466615
2      |LetsCrackIt ContestAle |in          |1582466741
       | Crackathon ...        |            |
3      |LetsCrackIt            |in          |1582467875
4      |LetsCrackIt            |in          |1582467883
```

I tried this query but it didn't work

```
SELECT COUNT(*), stt_hashtag 
FROM `st_trend_states` 
WHERE `country` = 'in' 
GROUP BY stt_hashtag
```

I want to count words and order by highest occuring desc

Comment: Please explain what didn't work. Did the query fail, wrong results, other?

Comment: wrong result in order and count also @user3783243

Comment: Can you please add what is returned and what should be returned? You have no `order by` in current query so order being incorrect is expected.

Comment: i want as twitter trend hashtags result @MagnusEriksson

Comment: You should rethink your database design. Having multiple values in one single column is not a good idea. Read up on [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) and your issue here would be a breeze (and faster)

Comment: total count of  
LetsCrackIt is 3 so it should be on top ...and another word with single occurance @user3783243

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with a query like this:

```
SELECT  count(*) as wordcount,
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(stt_hashtag, ' ', wordnr), ' ', -1) as singleword
FROM `st_trend_states` 
CROSS JOIN ( SELECT 1 as wordnr UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5) as wc
WHERE
    `stt_country` = 'in' 
AND
    wordnr <= CHAR_LENGTH(stt_hashtag) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(stt_hashtag,' ','')) +1
GROUP BY singleword
ORDER BY wordcount DESC, singleword ASC;
```

**Sample**

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM st_trend_states;
+----+---------------------------------------+-------------+------------+
| id | stt_hashtag                           | stt_country | stt_time   |
+----+---------------------------------------+-------------+------------+
|  1 | ClimateAction CleanSeas               | in          | 1582466615 |
|  2 | LetsCrackIt ContestAle Crackathon ... | in          | 1582466741 |
|  3 | LetsCrackIt                           | in          | 1582467875 |
|  4 | LetsCrackIt                           | in          | 1582467875 |
+----+---------------------------------------+-------------+------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

**The Query**

```
mysql> SELECT  count(*) as wordcount,
    -> SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(stt_hashtag, ' ', wordnr), ' ', -1) as singleword
    -> FROM `st_trend_states` 
    -> CROSS JOIN ( SELECT 1 as wordnr UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5) as wc
    -> WHERE
    -> `stt_country` = 'in' 
    -> AND
    -> wordnr <= CHAR_LENGTH(stt_hashtag) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(stt_hashtag,' ','')) +1
    -> GROUP BY singleword
    -> ORDER BY wordcount DESC, singleword ASC;
+-----------+---------------+
| wordcount | singleword    |
+-----------+---------------+
|         3 | LetsCrackIt   |
|         1 | ...           |
|         1 | CleanSeas     |
|         1 | ClimateAction |
|         1 | ContestAle    |
|         1 | Crackathon    |
+-----------+---------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: @work out - i have wrote a query for you. please test it

Comment: ya its working @Bernd Buffen